# MongoDB is not reusing freed disk space

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB is not reusing freed disk space when I delete and put files using `mongofiles`.

- I have MongoDB cluster of one `mongos`, one `config server` and one `shard server`.
- At initial state the shard server occupied `301MB` disk space.
- When I put a file of size `1021MB` using `mongofiles` into mongos `mongofiles -d test1 put sample1.bin` then the db `test1` size is `1.001GB` and disk occupied by `shard server` is `2.5G`
- When I delete the file `mongofiles -d test1 delete sample1.bin` then the db `test1` size `(1.001GB)` and shard server disk space `(2.5G)` remains same.
- Now I put another file of size `874MB` using mongofiles. Now the db `test1` size is `0.971GB` and shard server disk occupied space is `3.5GB`
- Here the db size is reduced as file size is `874MB`, but shard server disk space is increased.
- I repeated the steps `put` and `delete` using mongofiles

What I observed is db size is same as file size but the disk space used by shard server goes on increasing.

Instead of reusing, why disk space of `shard server` goes on increasing if I delete and put files.

Comment: Have you tried - db.runCommand({compact:'collectionName'})

Comment: @Aky_0788 I did that. But there is no change in disk space of `shard server`